# Is it possible to print a text message, if condition is not satisfied in protractor?

Tags: protractor

My code:

```
this.condition = function() {
        element(by.partialLinkText('Times Jobs')).isDisplayed().then(function (result) {
            if (result) {
                element(by.partialLinkText('Times Jobs')).click();
            } else {
                console.log('Times source not found')
            }
        });
    }
```

If "Times Jobs" is not presented in the page then it should display whatever text inside the else statement. How can i do that?

I don't want to make test fail, just i need to print that text in console.

Comment: What happens when you run the code you posted?

Comment: @MichalCharemza I am getting this error :  Failed: No element found using locator: By(partial link text, Times Jobs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this ::

```
this.condition = function() {
        element(by.partialLinkText('Times Jobs')).isPresent().then(function (result) {
            if (result) {
                element(by.partialLinkText('Times Jobs')).click();
            } else {
                console.log('Times source not found')
            }
        });
    }
```

as if the element is not present on the page than it give element not found error

Comment: It worked.. i changed my code isDisplayed() to isPresent() and now it is working fine...thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isPresent()`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37180293/1319998), but if you want to keep using `isDisplayed()`, you must handle the case of the element not being found in the error callback of its returned promise:

```
element(by.partialLinkText('Times Jobs')).isDisplayed().then(function (result) {
  if (result) {
    element(by.partialLinkText('Times Jobs')).click();
  } else {
    console.log('Times source in page but not displayed');
  }
}, function() {
  console.log('Times source not in page');  
});
```

Or, if you want to output the same message in both of the cases of not being 
in the page, or being in the page but not displayed, you can...

```
element(by.partialLinkText('Times Jobs')).isDisplayed().then(function (result) {
  if (result) {
    element(by.partialLinkText('Times Jobs')).click();
  } else {
    return protractor.promise.rejected();
  }
}).catch(function() {
  console.log('Times source not in page or in page and not displayed');  
});
```